# LiquiBase changeset is being picked up, but not showing up in databasechangelog or in the database

Tags: java-8, liquibase-hibernate

I created a new changeset to add a new column to an existing table as shown below. I also added the key-property to the hbm.xml file of the usergroup table. It does get picked up according to the logs, and ran successfully, but it does not show up on the databasechangelog table, and the changes are not being reflected in the usergroup table.

```
<changeSet author="changeTest" id="2018-10-25">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="USERGROUP" columnName="USERROLE"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <addColumn tableName="USERGROUP">
        <column name="USERROLE" type="VARCHAR(50 ${varcharUnit})" />
    </addColumn>

    <update tableName="USERGROUP">
        <column name="USERROLE" type="VARCHAR(50 ${varcharUnit})" value="user"/>
        <where>USERNAME = 'user1'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

The key-property is under a composite-id element, with 2 keys before it.

```
<key-property name="userRoleInGroup" type="string" >
    <column name="userRole" default="user"/>
</key-property>
```

Am I missing some update process for this?